# Why is my largest sub-square-matrix sum program not working with negative numbers?

Tags: c++

This program is meant to take in a square matrix of integers and outputs the largest sub-square-matrix sum.

The first line of input is an integer which indicates the dimension of the square matrix, followed by the actual matrix row-by-row.
My program only seems to work when using 1's for some reason and when I try to include a negative, the program gives a complete wrong answer.

Example Input1:
 3

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

Output: 45

Example Input2:
3

1 2 3

4 5 6

-7 -8 -9

Output: 16

NB: Since the largest square matrix is [2 3; 5 6] which sums to 16

My code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

#define bool int

using namespace std;

void printMaxSubSquare(bool M[10][10], int n)

{
int i,j;
int S[n][n];
int max_of_s, max_i, max_j;

// Set first column of S[][]
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    S[i][0] = M[i][0];

// Set first row of S[][]
for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
    S[0][j] = M[0][j];

// Construct other entries of S[][]
for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    for(j = 1; j < n; j++)
    {
        if(M[i][j] > -1 ){
            S[i][j] = min(S[i][j-1],min( S[i-1][j],
                            S[i-1][j-1])) + 1;
        }

        else
            S[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

// Find the maximum entry, and indexes of maximum entry in S[][]
max_of_s = S[0][0];
max_i = 0;
max_j = 0;

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {


        if(max_of_s < S[i][j])
        {
            max_of_s = S[i][j];
            max_i = i;
            max_j = j;
        }

        if(S[i][j]<0){
            S[i][j] = 0;
            max_i = 0;
            max_j = 0;
        }


    }
}

int sum = 0;

for(i = max_i; i > max_i - max_of_s; i--)
{
    for(j = max_j; j > max_j - max_of_s; j--)
    {
        sum = sum + M[i][j];
        cout << M[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

cout<<sum;
}



int main()

{
int n = 0;

cin>>n;

bool M[10][10];

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        cin>>M[i][j];
    }
}

cout<<endl;

printMaxSubSquare(M,n);
}
```

Comment: Please also post compiler and version. Variable-length arrays `int S[n][n]` and `<bits/stdc++.h>` are implentation defined. Behavior depends on compiler and version.

Answer (score 0):

You declared M as bool and so that defeats what you want when execute cin>>M[i][j]. Oh I see you wrote #define bool int ... that's not kosher
See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword